# How do I make my bot include what I said removing the command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
if (message.content.includes("<poll")) {
let embed = new DiscordMessage.Embed()
.setTitle(`Poll In ${message.guild.name}`)
.setDescription(the args that were in the other part of the command)
.setColor('RANDOM')
message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

I am trying to make it so where I put "the args that were in the other part of the command" shows like: If I say "<poll hello" the part in the embed would say "hello".

Comment: See this guide on how to make [commands with user inputs](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html).

Comment: The thing is, when they define args it has prefix in it but I don't use prefix

Comment: Then ignore the prefix trimming statements. [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the message content by space, (`message.content.split(' ');`) will return you the array, and then use that array for your commands.

Comment: Well now It only shows the first word.

const args = message.content.split(' ');
if (message.content.includes('<poll')) {
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`Poll In ${message.guild.name}`)
.setDescription(args[1])
.setColor('RANDOM')
message.channel.send(embed);
}

Comment: Okay in order to get everything after the command, [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them. Slice is to return the array after a particular index and join to join them by any character. Eg: `args.slice(1).join(' ');`

Comment: tysm! Now is there a way to  automatically make it add reactions on the poll message?